# How to fix 'ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package' in webscraping using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to import the class from a spider folder, file but it gives me the error.

I used following method to import the class:

```
 from .spiders.amazon_Spider import amazonSpider
```

Following is my files enlignment:

```
-amazonWebScraping
    -amazonWebScraping
         -spiders
             -amazon_spiders.py
         -scraper.py
```

I'm trying to access `class amazonSpider(scrapy.Spider)` from `amazon_spider.py` file, in `scraper.py` file but it's giving me the error

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) and [this](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) could help.

Comment: real bad namespacing?